# Insufficient Privileges when creating tables in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

I have granted the user in my connection to create tables, triggers, procedures, and sequence using sql+ (`grant create table to <my_user>`); however, that still does not allow me to create a table in that schema showing the error message:

> java.sql.sqlsyntaxerrorexception ora-01031 insufficient privileges

`select * from session_privs;` shows:

```
PRIVILEGE
UNLIMITED TABLESPACE
CREATE TABLE
CREATE CLUSTER
CREATE SEQUENCE
CREATE PROCEDURE
CREATE TRIGGER
CREATE TYPE
CREATE OPERATOR
CREATE INDEXTYPE
```

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong here? I am just setting up pl/sql developer at home, so everything is brand new. Does this have anything to do with `TABLESPACE`?

Comment: Show us exactly what DDL statements you are executing.  I tend to believe Oracle when it tells you that you haven't granted the privilege.  But it's hard to know where you went wrong without seeing exactly what you are doing.

Comment: `CREATE TABLE GLOBAL.GLB_COUNTRY`
`(`
`  COUNTRY_ID NUMBER(3, 0) NOT NULL` 
`, COUNTRY_SHORT_NAME VARCHAR2(20)` 
`, COUNTRY_LONG_NAME VARCHAR2(30)` 
`, CONSTRAINT GLB_COUNTRY_PK PRIMARY KEY` 
`  (`
`    COUNTRY_ID`
`  )`
`  ENABLE`
`);`

Comment: Are you logged in as the user `GLOBAL`?  Did you grant the `GLOBAL` user the `CREATE TABLE` privilege?

Comment: I had logged in as SYSTEM - when I logged in as GLOBAL it solved the issue! Thank you so much for the help feel kind of embarrassed:p

Comment: If you are trying to create a table in other schema then you should grant "create any table".

Comment: Stop logging in as SYSTEM (or SYS either). Period. End of story. Just stop it.

Answer (score 28):

Run the following command from a privileged user and re-connect with your user:

GRANT RESOURCE to my_user;

Comment: connect as SYSTEM and run this

Comment: This helped me. Thanks.