# Insufficient Privileges Create table

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, create-table, ora-01031

I am new with Sql Developer and I got this problem. I make connection but when I try to create table it shows me error:

> **ORA-01031:** *Insufficient Privileges.*

I try to find answer but I did not succeed.

Please help
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you or your dba should logon sys, and issue :

```
SQL> grant create any table to anonymous;
```

OR

```
SQL> grant create table to anonymous;
```

OR

```
SQL> grant resource to anonymous;
```

to have creating table privilege.

> the difference between  `create table` and `create any table` is that
>
> if you have create table privilege  then you can create a table in your
> own schema.but if you have create any  table system privilege then you
> can create table in any schema.also to  create an external table the
> valid privilege is create any table if you use  create table then it
> will show an error.

Comment: Why `create any table` rather than `create table`?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the chosen answer and it didn't work.
When you ask questions just wait until you recieve at least 3 answers and then give it green thick.

*Try this instead(run it with sys or system user):*
'GRANT RESOURCE to my_user; '

Source & already answered link:
[Insufficient Privileges when creating tables in Oracle SQL Developer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19216392/insufficient-privileges-when-creating-tables-in-oracle-sql-developer)

Comment: @Moeez answered, if any of these answers were informative for you, please consider voting to make it reachable and trustworthy for the community.